# How to tear a hole in cloth sail rendered as a plane mesh animated with a shader?

Tags: unity, shaders, animation, mesh, cloth

I have a procedurally animated sailcloth. It's just a square flat plane mesh with 144 vertices.
I use a shader to manipulate the vertices and make it "fill" with the wind.
All of that works fine.

Now how would I go about rendering damage on this flat plane mesh?
If I were to use a simulated cloth solution like Obi Cloth, it comes with tearing and holes out of the box, but the simulation is so expensive that it is unusable for my game (too many sails).
That's why I switched to shader magic for the sail animation: it performs much better.

The problem is how do I go about making holes/tears into these procedurally animated sails?

They always stay as a flat mesh, I would think this shouldn't be the hardest thing to do... But I am completely at a loss here.

The holes will "appear" based on cannonball hits to the sail.
The holes can be anywhere randomly, or at an exact vertex (procedural).
I would like to keep everything procedural( not cutting out holes in blender and switching between meshes, etc, as we are a small team).

If the holes are randomly placed on the mesh and dont take into account where exactly the cannonball hit the cloth mesh, then thats fine, I can probably upgrade it later to "translate" the hitpoint to the nearest vertex later, and go from there to make it more realistic.

I used Amplify Shader for the vertex displacement:
[image]

Comment: Can you show us 1. the shader you use for filling the sail, 2. a visual target for what a torn sail should look like in your game? Do you need to control the exact locations of the tears to align with the points where damage was dealt to the sail, or is it OK if the tears are always in the same places?

Comment: Thank you for your reply I updated the question.

Comment: The simple approach would be to just add an alpha mask to the texture of the sail, and cut a hole out of that alpha mask texture whenever the sail gets hit. Sure, the sail would not look super-realistic, because the holes have no influence on how the cloth flaps. But it should be good enough for most situations.